# Telerik InAppPurchase plugin on Android device worked once, now returns Product Not Available

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, telerik

I have a working alpha version Andriod Cordova app using Telerik plugin, InAppPurchase. I was able to do a test purchase for each of my CONSUMABLE products one time. Now all products return "Not Available" in my test account although their status is "VALID". The current version API of the plugin doesn't seem to have the method that sets the product to "consumed" so that the product is again "valid" and "available".

Can someone please explain how to reset the products so that the CONSUMABLE products are again available for repurchase?

Many thanks,

Fio

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue.

If you changed the Android Version number on the APK and installed it on your device, and did not upload it to Google Play, you will get "Not Available for Purchase."

Once you publish that version checkout will work again.

Comment: Nope. Modified version number, uploaded to play store. Still cannot purchase my items. I get a message "Item not available".Tried it under my account and a test account.